# How do I solve for vector $P$ in the matrix equation $s=A'B^{-1}A$?

Tags: matrices, regression, matrix-equations, regression-analysis

I would like to rearrange the matrix equation $s=A'B^{-1}A$ into the form $A=f(s,B)$ (i.e., some function of $s$ and $B$), where s is scalar, $A$ is $n\times 1$, $A'$ is the transpose of $A$, and $B$ is $n\times n$. I need a general solution, so that I can plug in values for $s$ and $R$ and solve for $P$. How should I go about this?

In case it helps, the equation in its current form calculates the squared multiple correlation ($R^2$) for the regression equation $y=x_1+x_2+...x_n$, given that $s=R^2$, $A$ is an $n\times 1$ vector of population correlations between y and each $x$, and $R$ is a square matrix of population correlations among the predictors themselves (so it's symmetric with a diagonal of 1's). My goal is to supply the multiple correlation and a set of predictors with known relationships, and find the correlations each predictor $x$ must have with the dependent variable $y$.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Assuming $s > 0$ and $B$ is positive definite, take any nonzero vector $v$, let $t = v' B^{-1} v$ and let $A = (s/t)^{1/2} v$.

Comment: When you say "sI" is that the same as saying that the product of matrices with dimensions (1x3)(3x3)(3x1) is a 1x1 matrix, s[1]? As you can tell, I'm not versed in matrix algebra beyond the very basics, but I'm basically trying to say that s will be a single real number.

Comment: Sorry, misread the original question.

Comment: So doing this in R, I would have:
v=matrix(c(.1,.2,.3))
t=t(v)%*%solve(B)%*%v

Comment: Wow, that really works well (ignore comment above). Thanks!

Comment: I'm now trying to find the steps between my original equation and the one solving for the vector, in other words showing the derivation of the latter from the former. Can you advise?